# VB.NET Unable to find data using datatable.select()

Tags: vb.net, linq, select, datatable, datagridview

dt is a datatable from ODBC, where i need to find a specific value

LookupCode is returning correct value from DataGrid

LookupRow is returning System.NullReferenceException but i'm sure that in dt there is data that I'm looking for

```
Imports System.Linq    
...
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim LookupRow As DataRow
Dim LookupCode As String

If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
   For Each row As DataGridViewRow In MagDataGridView.Rows
      LookupCode = row.Cells(1).Value
      LookupRow = dt.Select("'" & dt.Columns(0).ColumnName & "'='" & LookupCode & "'").FirstOrDefault
      row.Cells(5).Value = LookupRow.Item(1)
   Next
End If
```

[Screenshot of Compilator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pciz.png)

**After 1st comment**

If i change the line to `LookupRow = dt.Select(dt.Columns(0).ColumnName & "='" & LookupCode & "'").First`

then i have `unable to perform '=' on System.Int32 and System.String.”`

**Solved with this replacement of code:**

```
Dim fRow = From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
 Where row.Field(Of String)(dt.Columns(0).ColumnName) = LookupCode
 LookupRow = fRow.First
 r.Cells(5).Value = LookupRow.Item(1)
```

Comment: This is basic SQL. You don't put quotes around identifiers. You are comparing two literal text values and of course they're not going to be the same.

Comment: Also, why are you calling `FirstOrDefault` and then using the result as though it will never be `Nothing`? If the result might be `Nothing` then you have allow for that in subsequent code. If it can't be `Nothing` then don't call `FirstOrDefault` in the first place.

Comment: @John
  if i change to `LookupRow = dt.Select(dt.Columns(0).ColumnName & "='" & LookupCode & "'").First` then i have `'=' on System.Int32 and System.String.”` Error

Comment: Is there something missing from the code you posted?  Based on what you’ve shown us dt is a blank data table with no columns or rows.  So regardless of the validity of your query and types etc, it’s going to return nothing

Comment: That seems to suggest that `dt.Columns(0)` contains `Integer` values, so why are you comparing to a `String` value in the first place?

Comment: @user18387401 
`dt.Columns(0)` contains only `String` values and I'm comparing them to `LookupCode as string`

Comment: I solved the problem with different code:
                `Dim filteredRows = From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
                                   Where row.Field(Of String)(dt.Columns(0).ColumnName) = LookupCode
                LookupRow = filteredRows.First   rows.Cells(5).Value = LookupRow.Item(1)` and its working, anyone has idea why this code is working and the previous one no?